# Spring webflux, mongodb: Document is not saved into database

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am starting out with simple project in Spring Webflux + MongoDB.

I have difficulty understanding why this code saves object user into database:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody Mono<User> save(@ModelAttribute(value="user") User user){
            return reactiveUserRepository.save(user);   
        }   
    }
}
```

and when I replace the above function with this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String save(@ModelAttribute(value="user") User user){
        reactiveUserRepository.save(user);
        return "login";
    }
```

the document is not stored at all.

In the first case, the logging says:

```
2017-11-11 14:20:29.654 DEBUG 2828 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.d.m.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate       : Inserting Document containing fields: [_class] in collection: users
```

and in the second example no logging at all.

ReactiveUserRepository is empty interface extending ReactiveCrudRepository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ReactiveUserRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

I understand, that I can use MongoRepository instead of ReactiveCrudRepository and that will work. The question is, why saving document intoDB depends on the method return type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no subscribe for `Mono<User>` (which is returned by  `.save(user)`) in the second snippet; and when there is no subscribe nothing happens in reactor.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
String save(@ModelAttribute(value = "user") User user) {
  User user = reactiveUserRepository.save(user).block();
  return "login";
}
```

You can add `Mono.block()` operator to the Mono which is returned by `save(user)`. this will subscribe the mono and wait for result.

In the first snippet spring automatically subscribes for result, that's why it executes.

Comment: is this recommended, like should I block when saving?

Comment: What if I don't want to block?

Comment: @ArpitSuthar you can just return Publisher (Flux or Mono) from method and spring will subscribe for it.

Comment: @Nonika I don't want to get the response back its just logs which I am pushing to DB.

Comment: @ArpitSuthar just .subscribe() then

Comment: I tried that too but instead of data class name was getting saved in the DB, to I changed it to `.toFuture()` and it worked.